# How to plot multiple trends on the same plot

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I am trying to plot the trends in US firearm background checks for each state. The code below plots the trend of each states separately. How do I plot all the states (trends lines) on one plot coloured by states. Firearm dataset available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BuzzFeedNews/nics-firearm-background-checks/master/data/nics-firearm-background-checks.csv).

```
dat <- firearm %>% 
    mutate(date = ymd(paste(month, "01"))) %>%
    # filter(year(date) < 2010) %>%
    select(date, state, totals) %>%
    filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
    arrange(date) 

states <- unique(dat$state)
for (i in 1:length(states)) {
    state <- dat %>% filter(state == states[i])
    state_ts <- ts(state$totals, 
                 start = c(min(year(state$date)), 11), 
                 end = c(max(year(state$date)), 3), 
                 frequency = 12)
    trend <- decompose(state_ts)$trend
    plot(trend, main=states[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print more than 1 line on a base R graph, one needs to use `lines()` (or `points()` for each additional line

So in this case, here is the revised loop.  When i==1 use plot then use lines for i>2.  Also a different color is used for additional line.

```
for (i in 1:length(states)) {
   state <- dat %>% filter(state == states[i])
   state_ts <- ts(state$totals, 
                  start = c(min(year(state$date)), 11), 
                  end = c(max(year(state$date)), 3), 
                  frequency = 12)
   trend <- decompose(state_ts)$trend
   if (i==1) {
      plot(trend, col=colors()[i+1])
   }
   else { lines(trend, col=colors()[i+1])}
}
```